# How to print an array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am writing a program to read a directory of nested directories and files and get back a nested array that matches the file/directory structure.

I have the following:

```
dirs = File.join(<file_path>, "**", "*")
dirs_array = Dir.glob(dirs)
```

When I prints dirs_array, I get back a list of all the file paths but it's not in array format. However, when I call 'dirs_array.class' the output is Array. What am I missing here? And how do I get the dirs_array to print in array format?

Comment: How do you print it? How do you need it?

Comment: I just `puts dirs_array`

Comment: That won't show the structure. You might mean `p dirs_array`.

Comment: To clarify further: `p` calls `inspect` ([p docs](https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/p))

Answer (score 1):

You're likely getting an Array back, but you're not seeing it because `puts` tries to work with that and instead prints one entry per line. This can obscure the internals.

To show the structure:

```rb
puts dirs_array.inspect
```

There's also a shorthand form for this:

```
p dirs_array
```

Or if you like things *fancy* you can use the "pretty printer":

```
pp dirs_array
```

This form is more verbose, but can help reveal more complex structures.